# Java, making methods static

Tags: java, methods, static

I'm trying to make main call my method `getArtist()`, but when I do so, it tells me that I can't reference a non-static method from static context. I read around but I still don't understand it, how do I make `getArtist()` a static method, without naming it `public static String getArtist()`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mainArtist;
    String mainTitle;
    CD myCD = new CD("Awesomeguy", "AwesomeCDName");
    mainArtist = getArtist();
    System.out.println(mainArtist);
}

public String getArtist(){
    String person;
    person = artist;
    return person;
}
```

Comment: "*how do i make getArtist() a static method? without naming it public static String getArtist()*". It's impossible. You must use the `static` keyword.

Comment: perhaps you want `myCD.getArtist()`

Answer (score 5):

If this is code from your `CD` class, and you don't want to make `getArtist()` static, then the alternative is to call it on a `CD` instance.

```
CD myCD = new CD("Awesomeguy", "AwesomeCDName");
mainArtist = myCD.getArtist();
```

Answer (score 3):

Static means that the method is part of the class rather than the object.
An example of this is the math class where you call the method directly on the class name.

```
Math.round(4);
```

Instance means that it is part of the object, each instance has their own version of the method. To use an instance method you need to create an instance first.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner();
scan.next();
```

If you try to call an instance method from a static context then it doesn't know what instance to run it against, which is why you are getting the error.

Since the main method has to be static you have two options, first if you want the `getArtist` method as part of the class then make it static:

```
public static String getArtist(){
```

Then you can call it as you are in your code:

```
mainArtist = getArtist();
```

But since your CD class is storing data it is probably better for `getArtist` to be an instance method as you current have it. This means you want to call the method on an instance:

```
CD myCD = new CD("Awesomeguy", "AwesomeCDName");
mainArtist = myCD.getArtist();
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use the static keyword or in main, create an instance of the class that defines the getArtist function.

Comment: How do i go about creating an instance of the class that defines getArtist?

Comment: @user1801067 see John kuhelman's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mainArtist;
    String mainTitle;
    CD myCD = new CD("Awesomeguy", "AwesomeCDName");
    mainArtist = myCD.getArtist(); 
    System.out.println(mainArtist);
}

public String getArtist(){
    String person;
    person = artist;
    return person;
}
if you change the method public String getArtist() to public static String getArtist() 
then call mainArtist = getArtist();
```